# How to safely carry our manual migration from magento to shopify?

Tags: magento, migration, shopify, magento-1.7, shopping-cart

I have a store that I wanted to migrate manually from Magento to Shopify - Reason for manual migration is that i'm a developer myself and wanted to save some costs.

However since its the first time I'm doing this. Would love to know if you guys can guide me on how to go on about this manual migration!

Also, i am also open to simple use LitExtension in place of manual migration but I'm scared that it would be risky.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not a developer, so i usually go with migration apps. it's fast and doesn't require some additional effort. and, most importantly, the store's available online and there's no impact on the revenue. however, my preference is cart2cart. i've migrated a couple of my stores with this tool from magento to woocommerce. these were big ones, but the migration took only a few hours. you can try the free demo there and decide for yourself. good luck with your migration! hope my answer helped!